# How to Get an Audio File and decode to a base64 String?

Tags: java, android, web-services, file, base64

I need to take an audio file from my SD card (I have the path), but How can I convert to an base64 to put It in a String.  I need it to pass to an Web Service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
    private void doFileUpload(){
     byte[] videoBytes;
     try {
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath));

         byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
         int n;
         while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
             baos.write(buf, 0, n);

        String videoBytes = baos.toByteArray();


         video_str = Base64.encodeBytes(videoBytes);
            System.out.println("video array"+video_str);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }}
```

and download Base64 class from org.apache.ws.commons.util.Base64 or from http://iharder.net/base64

Answer (score 0):

Use org.apache.ws.commons.util.Base64 class, from apache ws-commons-utils

Comment: how can i use above class?